# Moving an element in array to the beginning with Javascript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

I'm working on an AngularJS filter to pick movies and have been looking to use multiple search words. If the movie has not been caught by the filter yet, it goes to the top of the array. Ultimately I'd like to order the array by hits but for the meantime I just want to set it up so that, if the movie is already in the search results array, it gets moved to the top of the array in order to be seen first. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
// New module:

var app = angular.module('movieFinder', []);

// Search function:

app.filter('searchFor', function() {

  return function(arr, searchString) {

    // Show all movies until search begins

    if(!searchString) {
        return arr;
    }

    var result = [];

    // Search for each word. Change to lowercase. Remove any punctuation. Split into array.

    searchArray = searchString.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").split(" ");

  // Work through each word.

  for (i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {

    // Work through each movie.

    angular.forEach(arr, function(movie) {

      if((movie.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchArray[i]) !== -1) || 
        (movie.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchArray[i]) !== -1) || 
        (movie.director.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchArray[i]) !== -1) || 
        (movie.country.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchArray[i]) !== -1) || 
        (movie.year.toString().indexOf(searchArray[i]) !== -1) || 
        (movie.genre.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchArray[i]) !== -1) || 
        (movie.keywords.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchArray[i]) !== -1)) {

          // If the movie is not listed...

          if (result.indexOf(movie) === -1) {

            // Insert at top of array

            result.unshift(movie);

          };

        };
      });
    }

    return result;

  }

});

// The controller

function MovieFinderController($scope){

  // The data model

  $scope.movies = [

    {
      title: 'The Beat That My Heart Skipped',
      description: 'Will Thomas still lead a life of crime and cruelty, just like his thuggish father, or will he pursue his dream of becoming a pianist?',
      director: 'Jacques Audiard',
      country: 'France',
      year: 2005,
      genre: 'Noir Thriller',
      cover: 'images/thebeatthatmyheartskipped.jpg',
      keywords: 'piano, gangster, broody, thug'
    },{
      title: 'Chungking Express',
      description: 'Two melancholy Hong Kong policemen fall in love: one with a mysterious female underworld figure, the other with a beautiful and ethereal server at a late-night restaurant he frequents.',
      director: 'Wong Kar Wai',
      country: 'Hong Kong',
      year: 1994,
      genre: 'Romantic Comedy',
      cover: 'images/chungkingexpress.jpg',
      keywords: 'fast food, cops, music, wigs, dancing, Chinese food, heartache, eating'
    } 
(...)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.unshift` to append things in the start of the array.

```
Array.prototype.unshift.apply(<your array>, <movies to be added at beginning>);
```